# External authentication with Azure Active Directory B2C

Tags: c#, azure, active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, aspnetboilerplate

Currently we are exploring the use of AspNetBoilerPlate (.NETCore and Agular) and one of the biggest pieces we need to be able to use is Azure Active Directory B2C. After trying various methods to get the login page to redirect over to the Azure B2C instance I have had no luck. My goal it so not need to override much if any of the base ABP code in order to accomplish this. In addition, I have what is recommended in the documentation with no success.

https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Zero/User-Management?searchKey=authentication#external-authentication

Sorry here are the pieces of code that I have with certain details removed:

Within the Portal.Web.Core project - Authentication I created a new class inheriting from ExternalAuthProviderApiBase and just hard-coded some values for the user. I still need to figure out how to get these from Azure AD B2C.

```
public class AzureActiveDirectoryB2CAuthProvider : ExternalAuthProviderApiBase
{
    public const string Name = "AzureB2C";

    public AzureActiveDirectoryB2CAuthProvider()
    {
    }

    public override Task<ExternalAuthUserInfo> GetUserInfo(string accessCode)
    {
        ExternalAuthUserInfo user = new ExternalAuthUserInfo();
        user.EmailAddress = "admin@aol.com";
        user.Name = "Administrator";
        user.Provider = this.ProviderInfo.Name;
        user.ProviderKey = "12345";
        user.Surname = "Cool Dude";

        return Task.FromResult(user);
    }
}
```

In the Portal.Web.Host --> Startup.cs I register the ExternalAuthProvider in the Configure method just after the app.UserAuthentication

```
var externalAuthConfiguration = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<ExternalAuthConfiguration>();
externalAuthConfiguration.Providers.Add(
    new ExternalLoginProviderInfo(
        AzureActiveDirectoryB2CAuthProvider.Name, string.Empty, string.Empty,
        typeof(AzureActiveDirectoryB2CAuthProvider)
    )
);
```

Now on the Angular2 side, I have added a reference to the MSAL.js library created by Microsoft to help handle the authentication.

Within the auth-route-guard.ts file I changed the canActivate method to call the login service which will try to determine if the user is already authenticated and if not redirect them to the Microsoft login page.

```
if (!this._sessionService.user) {
    //this._router.navigate(['/account/login']);
    this._loginService.updateUser();
    return false;
}
```

Below you will see the code from the modified login.service.ts file minus the Azure AD B2C details.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { TokenAuthServiceProxy, AuthenticateModel, AuthenticateResultModel, ExternalLoginProviderInfoModel, ExternalAuthenticateModel, ExternalAuthenticateResultModel } fro`enter code here`m '@shared/service-proxies/service-proxies';
import { UrlHelper } from '@shared/helpers/UrlHelper';
import { AppConsts } from '@shared/AppConsts';

import { MessageService } from '@abp/message/message.service';
import { LogService } from '@abp/log/log.service';
import { TokenService } from '@abp/auth/token.service';
import { UtilsService } from '@abp/utils/utils.service';

declare var Msal: any;

@Injectable()
export class LoginService {
    static readonly twoFactorRememberClientTokenName = 'TwoFactorRememberClientToken';
    private clientApplication: any;

    authenticateModel: AuthenticateModel;
    authenticateResult: AuthenticateResultModel;

    externalAuthenticateModel: ExternalAuthenticateModel;
    externalAuthenticateResult: ExternalAuthenticateResultModel;

    rememberMe: boolean;

    B2CTodoAccessTokenKey = "msal.idtoken";

    tenantConfig = {
        tenant: "",
        clientID: '',
        signUpSignInPolicy: "",
        b2cScopes: ["openid"]
    };

    // Configure the authority for Azure AD B2C
    authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/" + this.tenantConfig.tenant + "/" + this.tenantConfig.signUpSignInPolicy;

    /*
     * B2C SignIn SignUp Policy Configuration
     */
    //clientApplication = new Msal.UserAgentApplication(
    //    this.tenantConfig.clientID, this.authority,
    //    function (errorDesc: any, token: any, error: any, tokenType: any) {
    //        // Called after loginRedirect or acquireTokenPopup
    //    }
    //);

    constructor(
        private _tokenAuthService: TokenAuthServiceProxy,
        private _router: Router,
        private _utilsService: UtilsService,
        private _messageService: MessageService,
        private _tokenService: TokenService,
        private _logService: LogService,
    ) {
        this.clear();
        this.clientApplication =
            new Msal.UserAgentApplication(
                this.tenantConfig.clientID,
                this.authority,
                this.authCallback);
    }

    authenticate(finallyCallback?: () => void): void {
        finallyCallback = finallyCallback || (() => { });
        var model = new ExternalAuthenticateModel;
        model.authProvider = "AzureB2C";
        model.providerAccessCode = this.getAccessToken();
        model.providerKey = "12345";

        this._tokenAuthService
            .externalAuthenticate(model)
            .finally(finallyCallback)
            .subscribe((result: ExternalAuthenticateResultModel) => {
                this.processExternalAuthenticateResult(result);
        });
    }

    private processAuthenticateResult(authenticateResult: AuthenticateResultModel) {
        this.authenticateResult = authenticateResult;

        if (authenticateResult.accessToken) {
            //Successfully logged in
            this.login(authenticateResult.accessToken, authenticateResult.encryptedAccessToken, authenticateResult.expireInSeconds, this.rememberMe);

        } else {
            //Unexpected result!
            this._logService.warn('Unexpected authenticateResult!');
            this._router.navigate(['account/login']);
        }
    }

    private processExternalAuthenticateResult(externalAuthenticateResult: ExternalAuthenticateResultModel) {
        this.externalAuthenticateResult = externalAuthenticateResult;
        alert(externalAuthenticateResult.accessToken);
        if (externalAuthenticateResult.accessToken) {
            //Successfully logged in
            this.login(externalAuthenticateResult.accessToken, externalAuthenticateResult.encryptedAccessToken, externalAuthenticateResult.expireInSeconds, this.rememberMe);
        } else {
            //Unexpected result!

            this._logService.warn('Unexpected externalAuthenticateResult!');
        }
    }

    private login(accessToken: string, encryptedAccessToken: string, expireInSeconds: number, rememberMe?: boolean): void {
        var tokenExpireDate = rememberMe ? (new Date(new Date().getTime() + 1000 * expireInSeconds)) : undefined;

        this._tokenService.setToken(
            accessToken,
            tokenExpireDate
        );

        this._utilsService.setCookieValue(
            AppConsts.authorization.encrptedAuthTokenName,
            encryptedAccessToken,
            tokenExpireDate,
            abp.appPath
        );

        var initialUrl = UrlHelper.initialUrl;
        if (initialUrl.indexOf('/login') > 0) {
            initialUrl = AppConsts.appBaseUrl;
        }

        location.href = initialUrl;
    }

    private clear(): void {
        this.authenticateModel = new AuthenticateModel();
        this.authenticateModel.rememberClient = false;
        this.authenticateResult = null;
        this.rememberMe = false;
    }

    public AzureB2Clogin(): void {
        this.isOnline();
        this.clientApplication.loginRedirect(this.tenantConfig.b2cScopes);
    }

    saveAccessTokenToCache(accessToken: string): void {
        sessionStorage.setItem(this.B2CTodoAccessTokenKey, accessToken);
    };

    public isOnline(): boolean {
        return this.clientApplication.getUser() != null;
    };

    public getAccessToken(): string {
        alert('AccessToken: ' + sessionStorage.getItem(this.B2CTodoAccessTokenKey));
        return sessionStorage.getItem(this.B2CTodoAccessTokenKey);
    }

    public updateUser(): void {
        if (this.isOnline()) {
            this.authenticate();
        }
        else {
            this.AzureB2Clogin();
        }
    }

    public getAuthenticationToken(): Promise<string> {
        return this.clientApplication.acquireTokenSilent(this.tenantConfig.b2cScopes)
            .then(token => {
                alert("Got silent access token: " + token);
                return token;
            }).catch(error => {
                alert("Could not silently retrieve token from storage." + error);
                return this.clientApplication.acquireTokenPopup(this.tenantConfig.b2cScopes)
                    .then(token => {
                        alert("Got popup access token: "+ token);
                        return token;
                    }).catch(error => {
                        alert("Could not retrieve token from popup." + error);
                        this.clientApplication.acquireTokenRedirect(this.tenantConfig.b2cScopes);
                        return Promise.resolve("");
                    });
            });
    }

    private authCallback(errorDesc: any, token: any, error: any, tokenType: any) {
        if (token) {
            alert("Id token: " + token);
        }
        else {
            alert(error + ":" + errorDesc);
        }

        this.getAuthenticationToken();
    }
}
```

Finally index.html has the following script references added to it-->

```
<script src="https://secure.aadcdn.microsoftonline-p.com/lib/0.1.3/js/msal.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bluebird/3.3.4/bluebird.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fetch/2.0.3/fetch.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: External Authentication is the way to go. What did you do so far? show us the code

Comment: Sorry I should have added the code in the first place and didnt.

Comment: Did you get this solved. I answered a similar question in the AspNetZero.com forum for the aspnetboilerplate. I could add that here if needed. My answer used MVC/JQuery, and no MSAL though...